How can I easily make Emacs crash (on purpose)?
(info "(emacs) Crashing"):

Emacs is not supposed to crash, but if it does, it produces a crash report prior to exiting.

I am posting this for those who are interested in Emacs crashes and the reports.
Although it is generally difficult to intentionally and consistently cause a crash, it is possible.

just evaluate:
(clear-string (symbol-name t))

(This is NOT an Emacs bug.)

I initially thought this was because 
clearing the name of t causes Lisp to fail to match the symbol t in obarray (a special hash table implementation) and a lookup error for such a critical and fundamental symbol typically results in recursive errors.
However, NickD's comment inspired me, so I tried:
(clear-string (symbol-name 'w32-notification-notify))

and this indeed caused Emacs to crash.
So,

"t" (the name of t) is in read-only memory and trying to clear it is a no-no.


i confirm, it crashed my emacs. something i have never seen in my lifetime. any insights/opinions on why this code snippet causes the crash?

I presume that "t" (the name of t) is in read-only memory and trying to clear it is a no-no. nil would work as well.
